# Apache Nifi - version 0.5.0 - ExecuteSQL - org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: empty name

Tags: apache-nifi

With Nifi version 0.5.0 and following all the steps pointed here
https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=users@nifi.apache.org&q=subject:%22executesql%22&o=newest&f=1

I am still getting the same error **"org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException: empty name"**

My flow is

```
Generate Flow File > Fetch File -> Extract Text (here the value for the WHERE clause is exposed as a property "property1")> ExecuteSQL (Oracle DB) -> PutFile (results of the query)
```

The query executes fine in the Oracle DB

```
SELECT field1
FROM table
WHERE field1= '${property1}'
```

I am hitting dead ends, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in 0.5.x, a regression from 0.4.x. It is captured in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-1596 and has been fixed for the upcoming 0.6.0 release.

Comment: thanks Matt! this helps, I will try and download 0.4.1 and double check